# Python binding of a third party c++ library

Tags: python, c++, c++17, boost-python, python-bindings

I have a third party C ++ API, dynamic library (.so) for Linux with a header file.

My question is, can I directly write a bind file and use `boost.python` to create python bindings. I tried doing it and I added just one function to my bind.cc file from the API, compiled it and created another `.so` file. But when I imported this in python3 it threw an `ImportError`.

Here is my bind file:

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include "tp_api.h"
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(bb_api)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  def("tpGetAPIVersion", tpGetAPIVersion);
}
```

Build commands:

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC -undefined -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/include/python3.8 -lboost_python39 -o tp_api python3-config --extension-suffix
bind.cc
```

This creates: `tp_api.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

And then in python3:

```
from tp_api import tpGetAPIVersion
```

throws:

```
import Error undefined symbol: 
  _ZTIN5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_baseE.
```

Comment: Could you post what you tried?

Comment: Are you linking the boost/python library?  I would expect py_function_impl_base to be defined in one of the libraries.  See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/python/doc/html/building/choosing_a_boost_python_library_.html.

Comment: Please run `ldd tp_api.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and add the output to the question.

Comment: Yes, libboost.python was not linked. Thanks @CodieCodeMonkey and everyone else, bunch of brilliant people.